# When I render my animation these transparent/black rectangles keep showing up on the surface of the model, how do I make it so that these don't show?

Tags: rendering, animation

I've been making a rotating animation and whenever I render the video, these black rectangles keep showing up.
[image]

During rendering, these rectangles appear as transparent boxes
[image]

I've had these issues before and have never finished an animation because of it. Any ideas as to what the issue may be? Could the problem be my laptop? This is a somewhat old device and not necessarily the most powerful.
Here's the file just incase you need it;
https://mega.nz/fm/pTU2ARZS

Comment: That link to your file requires you to log in! Please use the supplied site to upload blend files s long as they are under 30Meg in size: https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on the page to add the link into your question.

Comment: Thanks for letiting me know, here's the link: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=XmLy671j" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/XmLy671j/)

Comment: That looks as if it might be a graphics issue from your images which could well be due to your laptop. What Blender version are you using and does the laptop have a graphics card with the most recent graphics driver?  It's difficult to tell from your blend file because you didn't include your material file (Color_Map_from_Mesh_defaultMat.png) and it doesn't look as if you've added any seams to your model or UV unwrapped it. You could include the materials file by using File > External Data > Pack Resources in Blender before saving and uploading.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was an issue with the texture image graphics.